# Docker swarm forawrd requests to only a single node

Tags: docker, load-balancing, docker-swarm

I have 2 machines in digital ocean cloud. 188.226.167.12, 146.185.135.232.
My application show the name of the host.

Each node contain a single replica of my service. 
When I access multiple times to: http://188.226.167.12:8080/ or http://146.185.135.232:8080/ , the host name doesn't change.

It means there is no load balancing for the requests.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: stavalfi/projecty:latest
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

How can I make a load balancer for my requests?

Comment: your IP addresses for your nodes are now publicly available on the internet. If their sensitive applications I suggest changing them immediately

Comment: As I described, its an application for showing the name of a computer. Nothing sensitive here.

Comment: Can you confirm these are Linux hosts and did you deploy with `docker stack deploy` or `docker-compose up`.

Comment: @BMitch Yes. Its linux hosts and I deployed using `docker stack deploy`.

Comment: Check that you have ports 7946/both (control) and 4789/udp (data) open between your nodes.

Comment: @BMitch Its working now!!! I didn't know those are essential. Please publish this as an answer and I will love to know what is 7946 port. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RR load balancing runs on the ingress network which is an overlay network. For overlay networking you need three ports opened:

- 7946/tcp (control)
- 7946/udp (control)
- 4789/udp (data)

Under the covers, this is VXLAN on Linux. If you enable IPSec on your overlay networks, you also need protocol 50. On the iptables CLI, this looks like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m udp --dport 7946 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4789 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p 50 -j ACCEPT
```

You can further limit those rules to only allow connections between docker nodes.